# How to set up differential equation for gravitational system?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, differential-equations

Consider the following system

[image]

Here, two immovable objects with mass $M$ are positioned $2d$ distance apart (in an empty universe). Meanwhile, an object of mass $m$ is placed somewhere above them on the same plane.

I found this system interesting because at first it resembled a simple harmonic oscillator, but on further inspection since the force of gravity doesn't increase linearly, it is not quite one (not dissimilar to a pendulum).

I'd like to model the motion of $m$ using the angle $\theta$ it makes with one of the unmovable masses $M$, but using Newtonian Mechanics, this seems quite nuanced.

I know that if we let $r$ be the distance between $m$ and one of the unmovable masses $M$, the force on the object that drives it forwards (along the blue dotted line) is (the factor of 2 comes from the fact that there's two unmovable masses pulling on it) $$F=\frac{2mMG}{r^2}\cdot\sin(\theta)$$
Since the blue distance squared plus $d^2$ is $r^2$, and $d\tan(\theta)$ gives the blue distance, we an rewrite the previous force expression purely in terms of $\theta$, which is $$F=\frac{2mMG\sin(\theta)}{d^2+d^2\tan^2(\theta)}$$

Now, given some position (the blue dotted line) $p(t)$, we can set the force equal to $m p''(t)$, which we will have to derive to make it in terms of $\theta$ (as a function of time). I will write stuff out in terms of functions of time to make things more clear. We have $$p(t) = d\tan(\theta(t))$$ so taking the second time derivative yields $$p''(t) = d\sec^2(\theta(t))(\theta''(t) + 2\theta'^2(t)\tan(\theta(t))$$

Since in our setup, theta's acceleration is negative, we have $$\frac{2MG\sin(\theta(t))}{d^2\sec^2(\theta(t))} = -d\sec^2(\theta(t))(\theta''(t) + 2\theta'^2(t)\tan(\theta(t)))$$

**Is this differential equation correct?** If I set all the constants equal to $1$, the plots Wolfram Alpha outputs make some sort of sense to me, and resemble a harmonic oscillator, but I'm not entirely sure.

[image]

Also, **is there a simpler way to derive this diffeq given that it is right in the first place**? (perhaps, using other formulations of classical mechanics?)

Thanks!

Comment: A pendulum is a harmonic oscillator....just not a *simple* harmonic oscillator

Comment: Ah my bad let me correct that

Comment: Try using $x$, the distance from the midpoint ,and start in terms of potential, $\propto 1/\sqrt(d^2+x^2)$, rather than force. Then use force is minus the potential gradient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\def \b {\mathbf}$

start with the position vector to the mass m

$$\b R=\left[ \begin {array}{c} d\\  d\tan \left( \varphi 
 \right) \end {array} \right]
$$

from here the velocity vector

$$\b v=\left[ \begin {array}{c} 0\\  {\frac {d\dot\varphi }{
 \left( \cos \left( \varphi  \right)  \right) ^{2}}}\end {array}
 \right] $$

the kinetic energy T

$$T=m\,\b v\cdot \b v$$

the potential energy U

$$U=2\,\frac{m\,M\,G}{\left(\b R\cdot\b R\right)^{1/2}}$$

and with Euler Langrage method  you obtain this differential  equation

$$\ddot\varphi+{\frac {\sin \left( \varphi  \right)  \left( -2\,{\dot\varphi }^{2}{d}^{3
}+M\,G \left( \cos \left( \varphi  \right)  \right) ^{5} \right) }{\cos
 \left( \varphi  \right) {d}^{3}}}
=0$$

but where is the "pendulum " in this equation ?

**Phase diagram**

initial condition

$~\varphi(0)=1~,\dot\varphi(0)=0$

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the Lagrangian version of the diffeq! (there is no pendulum i was just mentioning it as a passing remark) Just a slight question though - wolfram alpha's plots on of the diffeq don't resemble a harmonic oscillator (https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=f%27%27%28x%29+-+%28sin%28f%28x%29%29+*+%28-2+f%27%28x%29%5E2+%2B+cos%28f%28x%29%29%5E5%29%29%2F%28cos%28f%28x%29%29%29%3D0) is it supposed to be like this? It seems if we swap the sign on the MG cosine term, it fixes itself... I could also just be wrong lmao